# Unwanted timestamp when using print in python

Tags: python, printing, timestamp, autobahn

I am using autobahn[twisted] to achieve some WAMP communication. While subscribing to a topic a getting feed from it i print it. When i do it i get something like this:

```
2016-09-25T21:13:29+0200 (u'USDT_ETH', u'12.94669009', u'12.99998074', u'12.90000334', u'0.00035594', u'18396.86929477', u'1422.19525455', 0, u'13.14200000', u'12.80000000')
```

I have sacrificed too many hours to take it out. And yes, i tested other things to print, it print without this timestamp. This is my code:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner

class PushReactor(ApplicationSession):
        @inlineCallbacks
        def onJoin(self, details):
                print "subscribed"
                yield self.subscribe(self.onTick, u'ticker')

        def onTick(self, *args):
                print args

if __name__ == '__main__':
        runner = ApplicationRunner(u'wss://api.poloniex.com', u'realm1')
        runner.run(PushReactor)
```

How can i remove this timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout` are redirected to a twisted logger.

You need to change the logging format before running you app.

See: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.1/core/howto/logger.html

### How to reproduce

You can reproduce your problem with this simple application:

```
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationRunner

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hello1")
    runner = ApplicationRunner(u'wss://api.poloniex.com', u'realm1')
    print("hello2")
    runner.run(None)
    print("hello3")
```

When the process is killed, you'll see:

```
hello1
hello2
2016-09-26T14:08:13+0200 Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2016-09-26T14:08:13+0200 Main loop terminated.
2016-09-26T14:08:13+0200 hello3
```

During application launching, `stdout` (and `stderr`) are redirected to a file-like object (of class `twisted.logger._io.LoggingFile`).

Every call to `print` or `write` are changed in twister log messages (one for each line).

The redirection is done in the class `twisted.logger._global.LogBeginner`, look at the `beginLoggingTo` method.

Comment: But i am not using logger, the source is above. Im just using print function.

Comment: Yes, I know. Twister is doing that!

Comment: Im blind, i was doing something like:
    logs = twisted.logger.globalLogBeginner
    logs.beginLoggingTo(None,False,False)
but i dont know what observer is here i dont want anything ot be observable other than ticks